# Unable to assign strings to a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, string, vector

I am trying to write a code in c++ while hashing. For that I am trying to push strings in a vector of vectors. But it is showing a segmentation fault.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
int n,ind,inr;
cin >> n;
int j=0;    
vector<string> a;
vector<vector <string>> v(n);
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    v.push_back(a);
}                   
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    int m;
    string name;
    cin>>m;
    cin>>name;
    ind=m%2039;
        v[ind][j]=name;
    j=0;
    cout<<name<<endl;
}
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself, what is the size of the nested vectors in `v` (or another way: what is the size of `a`)?

Comment: `j` is always zero ???

Comment: BTW: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: Not only that, but you'll be surprised to learn that the size of `v` turns out to be not `n` values, but twice as much. As far as segfaults go, there are so many different reasons for them, here, it's difficult to decide where to start.

Comment: `v.at(ind).at(j)` would exposed the problem quickly.

Answer (score 1):

For starters neither of sub-vectors of the vector `v` has elements.

In this declaration

```
vector<vector <string>> v(n);
```

there is declared a vector with n empty sub-vectors.

Then in this loop

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    v.push_back(a);
}
```

you are appending one more n empty sub-vectors to the vector `v`. As a result the vector `v` has 2 * n empty sub-vectors.

In this statement

```
ind=m%2039;
```

there is used a magic number `2039`. The result of the expression

```
m%2039
```

can be greater than or equal to 2 * n.

So in this statement

```
v[ind][j]=name;
```

using the both indices (especially for empty sub-vectors of the vector v) results in undefined behavior.

Instead of a vector of sub-vectors you could use ths standard container std::map declared for example like

```
std::map<unsigned int, std::vector<std::string>> m;
```